# Counterexample of consistent measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are consistent if $\mu(A\times B)=\nu(B\times  A)$. Is this an example of non-consistent measure : $$\mu(dx\times dy)=\delta _0(dx)m(dy)=\nu(dx\times dy),$$

where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\delta _0$ the Dirac mass at $0$. It's stupid, but they look to be equal, but when I think a bit : $$\mu(\{0\}\times [1,2])=1\quad \text{but}\quad \nu([1,2]\times \{0\})=0.$$

Is the fact that $\mu=\nu$ a problem or I have to take an other counterexample ?

Comment: This seems like a slightly weird definition to me, but as stated this is an example.

Comment: @Ian: the correct definition is $\nu _{1,2}(A_1\times A_2)=\nu_{\sigma (1),\sigma (2)}(A_{\sigma (1)},A_{\sigma (2)})$ for all permutation of $\{1,2\}$, but this is equivalent to my definition, no ?

Comment: Then the idea is that $\nu_{i,j}$ is intuitively one object (a vector of measures indexed by permutations), so your example makes sense from that point of view.

Comment: There is a notion of consistency of a family of measures in the product which is used to state a hypothesis of [Kolmogorov extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem), but it goes [like this](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matsr/ProbI/Lecture2.pdf#page=4).

Comment: @logarithm: what do you mean by "but it goes like this" ? My version of kolmogorov extension is not as general as yours... but anyway, I think my example is a good counter example.

Comment: I meant that the definition used for Kolmogorov's theorem goes like the definition given in the link at the words 'like this', which is different from what you wrote. I added the comment given the likelihood that you are studying this theorem, but copied or interpreted wrongly the definition of 'consistent family of measures' that is used there.

Comment: @logarithm: I really don't see in what your comments are related to my original question... It's like if I ask : which color trees are, and you answer me 32... doesn't make any sense...

Comment: No, it is more like if you ask 'witch kohol twees arg', and I said 'It is likely that you wanted to ask "which color trees are"'. That happens when you ask something that makes no sense but that resembles vaguely some useful concept. That's the sense it makes, pointing you in the right direction when it looks, very likely, that you read something and didn't understand what you read.